# How to change title of more tab item?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tabbar

I searched a lot of web-site about this topic and try some solutions:

**1)Changing navigationItem title**

I changed navigationItem title but More tabItem is not changed.

**2)Changing tabbarItem title**

```
[tabBarController moreNavigationController].tabBarItem.title = @"Morre";
```

It didnt work either.

**3)Creating a new tabbarItem and assigning to it:**

```
 [tabBarController moreNavigationController].tabBarItem.= newlyCreatedTabBarItem;
```

I didnt work too.

There is also an alternative way to create more tab like a normal tabBar item. However, in that way configuration of tabBar Items become impossible. I also need "Edit" button in more tab.

I only managed to change badgeValue which has no value for me:

```
 [tabBarController moreNavigationController].tabBarItem.badgeValue = @"100";
```

So,is there a way to change title of more tabBar Item?

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you mean... I know you can change the name of tabs in interface builder, open mainwindow.xib, select "Tab Bar Controller", and under Tab Bar Controller Attributes, change the Title of the tab you want.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I was able to manage doing was changing the title of the controller

```
 self.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.topItem?.title = self.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.topItem?.title?.uppercased()
```

but this does not seems to influence the tab bar :/